# How to invoke TryValidateObject without creating ValidationErrors?

Tags: wpf

1. I am using some attribute based validation.
2. I wish to condition the submit command based on the boolean result of TryValidateObject. I need this to return without adding any validation errors to the ValidationErrors Collection. Otherwise a newly added record will immediately show errors - even before the users has keyed any input.
   This happens because the CanExecute method of the submit command executes immediately.
3. When I have finished with the current record (or on exit from the current field) I will call ValidateObject which should produce errors.

The problem seems to be that the ValidationAttribute class has no way to determine if its IsValid method is being invoked by TryValidateObject or ValidateObject. n.b. The IsValid method is where I add ValidationErrors to the ValidationResults collection.

How can I solve this.

Comment: Why don't you simply ignore the `ICollection` that you are passing to `Validator.TryValidateObject`?

Comment: I have subverted the Items parameter to the ValidationContext as follows. If I am calling TryValidate then I pass a one item Dictionary. (This is necessary as ValidationContext automatically creates an empty Items collection). My validators can then distinguish how they were called and not add to the ValidationErrors collection. This is an obscene hack.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a code sample of what you are tying to do if you want anyone to be able to help you. Your comment doesn't make much sense without one.